# Parsing JSON hash with each generates "can't convert String into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, hash

I am parsing JSON from an API with the following code:

```
def json_test
    content = open("API URL").read  
    json = JSON.parse(content)
    json.each do |a|
        puts a["first_name"]
    end
end
```

The reason I'm using each is because the API request will return an array of hashes for multiple users, like this:

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "first_name": "John"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "first_name": "Bob"
}]
```

However, the API will return just a hash if the request only returns a single user, like thus:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "first_name": "Bob"
}
```

This is where I'm getting the error message: can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

I've been searching for a good way to be able to parse when it's not returning an array but just a hash and I'm stumped. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.wrap`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap) is designed just for this purpose.

> Wraps its argument in an array unless it is already an array (or array-like).

```
Array.wrap({ a: 1 }) # => [{ a: 1 }]
Array.wrap [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }] # => [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]
```

Comment: Note: This is rails/active_support only.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I was looking in the Ruby docs instead of Rails docs, hence why I missed the method.

Comment: Look at the other extensions in active support too. They contain a lot of useful things that are good to know about.

Answer (score 0):

One way is putting it all inside a single element array and flattening it:

```
json = [JSON.parse(content)].flatten
```

If it is not an array, the flatten will be noop. If it is, the extra array layer will be removed.